# how to return a list of url from the coding below

Tags: java, url

as title shows, how do i return a list of urls under (a href) reference and display it in a text file ? The code below return the html form a a website.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            URL my_url = new URL("http://www.placeofjo.blogspot.com/");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream()));
            String strTemp = "";
            while(null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){
                System.out.println(strTemp);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sound like you want to be using an HTML parsing library like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), rather than getting into the hassle of parsing the HTML yourself.  The HtmlUnit code would be as simple as:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.placeofjo.blogspot.com/");

//  Then iterate through
for (DomElement element : page.getElementsByTagName("a")){
    String link = ((HtmlAnchor)element).getHrefAttribute();
    System.out.println(link);
}
```

Gives output of:

```
http://www.twitter.com/jozefinfin/
http://www.facebook.com/jozefinfin/
http://placeofjo.blogspot.com/2008_08_01_archive.html
... etc etc
http://placeofjo.blogspot.com/2011_02_01_archive.html
http://endlessdance.blogspot.com
http://blogskins.com/me/aaaaaa
http://weheartit.com
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply and attention..i am currently testing your code..but i got this error (HTML anchor cannot be resolved to a type).. would appreciate it if you could guide me ^^

Comment: I tested the code briefly here.  `HtmlAnchor` is in the latest htmlunit release (2.8) which you can download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/2.8/

Comment: OK I modified my answer - just had to turn javascript off.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try parsing the HTML with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and collect all the anchor tags from the page.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit (2)**

If you're looking for a robust solution (or might need to extend to parsing more HTML), then check out one of the other answers here. If you just want a quick-and-dirty, one time solution you might consider regex.

---

If I understand you correctly, you want to extract the `href` values for all `<a>` tags in the HTML you're fetching.

You can use [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Something like

```
String regex = "<a\s.*href=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find())
{
    String urlStr = m.group();
}
```

**Edit (1)**

Corrected the regex - we want reluctant quantifiers otherwise we'll end up getting everything!

Comment: You cannot parse HTML with regex.  See the top answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for a good explanation.

Comment: I can see this leading towards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Well, if all you are looking for is `href="something"` then regex would be fine.

Comment: The questioner is looking for all `href="something"` inside well-formed anchor elements, taking into account possible non-standard spacing and other edge cases.  Not as simple as it first seems.  For example, the current version posted would fail on <a target="_blank" href="http://example.com">

Comment: @mjg123 - You're right, if your applications calls for a full-fledged HTML scraper/parser then regex is too brittle to work well. However, if you have a specialized case or have limited, known HTML to work with then an HTML parser is probably overkill. I think both approaches have their place - regex's being for simple, quick, one time jobs.